# python3 loop on listener based on keyboard pressed or released

Tags: python

I tried running this code and using the insert key to activate the status, and I confirmed in the debug that it actually enters status = True, but it never stays in the loop, I can't understand why it doesn't stay in the loop when I click on insert key.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key

STATUS = False

def on_press(key):
    
    global STATUS
    
    if key == Key.insert:
        
        STATUS = True

def on_release(key):
    
    global STATUS
    
    if key == Key.end:
        
        STATUS = False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    
    while STATUS:
        
        print('on loop')
        
        pass

    listener.join()
```

Comment: `STATUS = False`, and so the loop doesn't even start. You'd need a rather big miracle to succeed with pressing insert and thus have the `STATUS = True` line running after the code initializes `listener`, but before it reaches the `while`. Try with `STATUS = True` at the start.

Comment: @tevemadar but i want no start on loop, loop can be started when insert it`s pressed.